# Problem in deducing gradient in spherical coordinates.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, intuition, spherical-coordinates

I know the differential displacement in spherical coordinate as $$dr \cdot \widehat{r}+ r d\theta\cdot\widehat{\theta} + r\sin\theta d\phi\cdot \widehat{\phi}$$. But I can't figure out how the gradient is $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial r}\cdot\widehat{r} + \dfrac{1}{r}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\cdot\widehat{\theta} + \dfrac{1}{r\sin\theta}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial \phi}\cdot\widehat{\phi}$. Can anyone show me the deduction please? I am new to this & came across it when was studying Schroedinger's equation in spherical coordinate form.

Comment: [This book](https://books.google.fr/books?id=8FVk_KRY7zwC&lpg=PP1&hl=it&pg=PA42#v=onepage&q&f=false) is a very good source for your studies.

Comment: This book seems really nice. You can look at [this question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/78510/derive-vector-gradient-in-spherical-coordinates-from-first-principles/78514#78514) and my answer to this [follow up](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1242662/how-to-derive-r-theta-phi-for-the-sperical-coordinate-gradient/1242663#1242663), too.

Answer (score 1):

Following this answer, https://math.stackexchange.com/a/587298/169296, you can use  :
$$ df = \frac{\partial f}{ \partial r} dr + \frac{\partial f}{ \partial \theta} d \theta + \frac{\partial f}{ \partial \phi} d\phi = \vec{\nabla f }\cdot \vec{dr}$$ 
Since $\vec{e_r} , \vec{e_\theta} $ and $ \vec{e_\phi}$ is a set of basis vectors you can suppose that $\vec{\nabla f } = \alpha  \vec{e_r} + \beta \vec{e_\theta} + \gamma \vec{e_\phi}$.

Then you will find your answer by identifying the coefficients using your expression of $\vec{dr}$.

Comment: Very nice. I would like to point out the similitude between this method and the one that [one can find here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalCoordinates.html) to compute $\partial_x, \partial_y, \partial_z$ in terms of $\partial_r, \partial_\theta, \partial_\phi$. (Read from "To express partial derivatives with respect to Cartesian axes in terms of partial derivatives of the spherical coordinates ...").